# How to calculate the number of loop this nested for loop will run given that the inner loop index always greater than outer loop?

Tags: performance, for-loop

I have run into a program where there are two nested loops in this manner

```
for k=1:K-1
    for ell=k+1:K
        do something
    end
end
```

How do I calculate the number of total loops this program will run mathematically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a counter to count the amount of times the loop iterates.

```
int myCounter = 0
for k=1:K-1
    for ell=k+1:K
        do something
        myCounter++
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you but I mean mathematically

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `K == 10` for the sake of the exemple.

`k` will to from `1` to `9`.

For:

- `k == 1`, `ell` goes from `2` to `10`, that's 9 iterations
- `k == 2`, `ell` goes from `3` to `10`, that's 8 iterations
- ...
- `k == 9`, `ell` goes from `10` to `10`, that's 1 iteration

You get `9 + 8 + ... + 1` (or `1 + ... + 8 + 9`), thus `45` iterations.

If you generalise this, you may know that the sum of integer values from `1` to `n` is `n * (n + 1) / 2`.

Substitute `n` by your value `K - 1`, and you should have your answer.

Comment: I am sorry but does your approach just count the number of iteration of the inner loop ?

Comment: It does. Add ˋK - 1` if you want to add the outer loop count.

Comment: So the total iteration of both loop would be 0.5*K*(K-1) right ?
Because 0.5*10*(10-1) = 45